# 'Boring' is to 'bores' as 'tedious' is to what?

Tags: single-word-requests, verbs, nouns

I've always found myself unable to find any information about this...

If a boring action **bores** me, then what does a tedious action do? I am inclined to say "it tedes me", but I am almost certain this makes no sense. Does such a word exist? Can someone shed some light on this?

Thanks.

Comment: To you, something tedious is a tedium. In other words, you find a tedious action to be a tedium. Sorry, you can't say "It tedes me"! (Well, strictly speaking you can, but most folks won't understand you.). I think you can also say that you find--or have found--something (fill in the blank) to be a tedium.

Comment: There's no guarantee of a plug to fill a lexical gap, especially when there is no obvious gap here. 'bored' and 'boring' and 'bore' are all related by regular morphological rules. 'tedious' has no obvious analog (it's not formed from a verb.)

Comment: Zen - no such word exists.  It's just that simple.  Precisely as Mitch says "There's no guarantee of a plug to fill a lexical gap".

Comment: @JoeBlow So there just simply isn't a verb form of tedious? I guess I assumed that one may have been developed from the usual rules of the latin -ium suffix, but I'm unaware of what they may be...

Comment: "So there just simply isn't a verb form of tedious?"  Yes, that is correct.  I think three people have said it now.  More importantly, as Mitch said and I said he said, **this is absolutely commonplace in English**.

Comment: note BTW that "boring" is quite complicated.  "a boring film" adjective "the film is boring the audience" verb.  etc.  note too that in your example fragment, "a boring action bores me" in fact *you are not actually using the word in two different forms on the same 'thing' to demonstrate two forms - it is two completely unrelated fragments*.  one is about 'action' and one is about 'me'.

Comment: Yea they are unrelated, but they still depend on each other. You could never say a boring action kicks me. That makes no sense. It bores me because it is boring. I was merely curious as to whether or not the verb form actually exists. This has been answered, it's all I needed to know

Comment: "... as 'tedious' is to single-word-requests."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Boring is not a stem word, it comes from the stem word bore. Bore can be a verb (to bore) or a noun (he is such a bore), and the -ing suffix is used to turn the verb into an adjective.

Tedious is a stem word, and an adjective. **It is not derived from a verb stem. Not all adjectives need to be derived from verb stems**.

If you want a word to describe how doing something tedious makes you feel, how about:

> Frustrates

Answer (score 3):

Because the definition of *tedious* (according to [Merriam Webster](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/tedious) is:

> :  tiresome because of length or dullness :  boring *< a tedious public ceremony>*

You can say that something tedious is *tiresome* and that it tires you [out].

[Collins](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/tedious) defines it as:

> causing fatigue or tedium; monotonous

So you could say that something tedious *fatigues* you.

[The Free Dictionary](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/tedious) defines it as:

> 1. Tiresome by reason of length, slowness, or dullness; boring. See Synonyms at boring

So you could also say that tedious things *bore* you.